# Wiremock standalone - Fetching values from request xml for a mock Soap service

Tags: soap, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I've been trying to create a stub system for a SOAP service using wiremock standalone. I've got the response.xml s ready and I'm required to return them based on an id value in the SOAP request xml.
For example,
Soap Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddressType>
            <addressId>Q1004DB</addressId>
        </AddressType>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As I mentioned before, I have response xmls set for each of the address Ids. In this case, I've got  a response xml named **Q1004DB.xml** which should be returned as response of this request. So I'm trying to figure out a logic to be put in place which will enable me to do this.

It would be great if someone can help me with how I can implement a logic in wiremock standalone where I can return a response based on the values in the input request xml. Thanks in advance !

As a first step, I tried returning the addressId as the response. I followed a couple of answers from StackOverflow and saw this format but this doesn't seem to work. Can someone please tell what might be wrong here ?

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "/ws/AddressSoapService",
    "method": "POST"
  },
  "response": {
    "body": "{{$.addressType.addressId}}",
    "headers": {
      "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0",
      "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
      "Web-Service": "DataFlex 18.1",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type",
      "Date": "Tue, 26 Jun 2018 07:45:47 GMT",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
      "Cache-Control": "private, max-age=0",
      "Content-Type": "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `xPath` template helper to extract values from the request in this case.

Assuming you want to generate a response that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <AddressType>
            <addressId>Q1004DB</addressId>
        </AddressType>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then you'd need a stub definition like this:

```json
{
  "name" : "SOAP example",
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/ws/AddressSoapService",
    "method" : "POST"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n    <soap:Body>\n        <MyResponse>\n            <addressId>{{xPath request.body '//AddressType/addressId/text()'}}</addressId>\n        </MyResponse>\n    </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/xml"
    },
    "transformers" : [ "response-template" ]
  }
}
```

Note that the body is inlined here. You could also put the body into a file and reference it and it would work the same way.